# time zone example not working in emulator

Tags: android

```xml
<receiver android:name=".ExampleBroadCastReceiver" 
    android:enabled="true"> 
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED"/> 
    </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

```java
package com.broadcastreceiver;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class ExampleBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver { 
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.d("ExmampleBroadcastReceiver", "intent=" + intent); 
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context,Login.class); 
        context.startActivity(intent1); 
    } 
}
```

I run this above code change the time zone in settings not calling other activity. Can anybody tell what the problem is?

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue, and this thread helped me get TimeZone updates working, however I still wasn't getting notifications for Date/Time changes.  I finally found that there's a difference in what you specify in your manifest file and what your broadcast receiver uses when filtering intents.  While it *IS* documented in the Android Intent reference, it is very easy to overlook!

In your AndroidManifest.xml file, use the following:

```
  <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
      <!-- NOTE: action.TIME_SET maps to an Intent.TIME_CHANGED broadcast message -->
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" /> 
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

And in your receiver class:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  private static final String TAG = "MyReceiver";
  private static boolean DEBUG = true;

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final String PROC = "onReceive";

    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
        if (DEBUG) { Log.v(TAG, PROC + ": ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED received"); }
    }
    // NOTE: this was triggered by action.TIME_SET in the manifest file!
    else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED)) {
      if (DEBUG) { Log.v(TAG, PROC + ": ACTION_TIME_CHANGED received"); }
    }
    else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED)) {
      if (DEBUG) { Log.v(TAG, PROC + ": ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED received"); }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't working because the intents are wrong. Replace the ones above with:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME" />
</intent-filter>
```

Then go to the Settings area and change the timezone.

Comment: I don't think this is correct... I don't see any intent named "android.intent.action.TIME" in the docs.  Can you provide a ref?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you didn't include the following lines in your `AndroidManifext.xml`, did you?

```
 <receiver android:name=".ExampleBroadcastReceiver" android:enabled="false">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />
         <action android:name="android.intent.ACTION_TIME" />
     </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```