# Get information when user change time on phone

Tags: android, time, notifications

Hey,
is there any easy way to get information when user will change time in android settings?
I mean that I'm looking for better solution than thread which is checking the time every one minute and compare with current time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Broadcase receiver [Here is an example](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/10/android-developer-tutorial-part-11.html)

Comment: OK So what about if the activity will be in background?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to [`ACTION_TIME_CHANGED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIME_CHANGED) or [`ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED) or both broadcasts.

Answer (score 0):

I just posted a reply to thread [time zone example not working in emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618267/time-zone-example-not-working-in-emulator) which shows how you must be careful to specify action.TIME_SET in your manifest file, and filter for Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED in your broadcast receiver.